# How to install TAILS as the primary OS on my Hardisk?

Tags: windows, tails

Before you refer me to it, i have read [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/can-tails-be-installed-as-primary-os)
I would like to know how I can install TAILS as the primary (ideally the only, as I would like to wipe others) OS on a windows computer. I have access to computers other than the one I wish to run TAILS on, so i would be able to use them to handle pre-downoads/modifications etc.

I'm not too worried about disabling the amnesiac features, as files and changes can be saved into the persistent volume if required, only it doesn't happen automatically.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at the [Tails FAQs](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index5h1)

Comment: i would advise you to use [Tails' persistent volume](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/configure/index.en.html) or [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/).

Comment: You've referred to my previous question, which seems to be asking the same thing. How is yours not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

This is a time consuming process because it was built on the basis of a Live Linux environment. I would suggest not trying to modify TAILS to be a persistent OS, but rather take an OS and apply the design and features following their documentation. [Here](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/) I have not seen a way to *simply* port all the configuration and options to a persistent disk. Unless you someone with a lot of Linux OS development experience, I believe it may not be worth it.

If you don't heed that warning, here are the details of how TAILS is built. [Building a Tails Image](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/build/) It is very resource intensive to build but a good way to start learning how it's put together.

I also wouldn't expect much help from the devs because the basis of their design hinges on it being a temporary environment and wouldn't be interested in supporting a fork.