# Will the Underwritten method for using TAILS work?

Tags: anonymity, tails

I have read [THIS](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6902/how-to-install-tails-as-the-primary-os-on-my-hardisk) and [THIS](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/can-tails-be-installed-as-primary-os) and I would also like to use tails as my primary OS. Before I go any further, please understand that this is mainly and academic exercise. So im not too bothered about the slight impracticality of the hardware work in this project.

I want to buy [THIS](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_odkw=dell%20inspiron%203000&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR11.TRC1.A0.H0.Xdell%20mini%2010.TRS0&_nkw=dell%20mini%2010&_sacat=0) computer as a cheap way to try this out. I will remove the hard drive, then another one of the USB ports, and resolved it to the motherboard via a few inches of wire. I will then insert a 1 male to 2 female USB port splitter into the now extended USB port, and put a tails usb stick into one of the resulting female ports. I will keep the cables etc out of the way, with insulation tape in the void where the hard drive was. The remaining empty female USB port will then be used as the original motherboard USB port was (I will position it at the edge of the board, and secure it with tape) so that other usb devices can be connected as they were before.

Then, if I power on the computer, tails will be the only available OS, and it will boot. Right?

I just posted on here to make sure that this will work  as this is my first time doing anything at all like this. Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing is hard lining a USB drive into a computer. You could similarly just image the TAILS image to a hard drive so that you don't have to worry about whether the USB drive will last. This won't make the system persistent, it will just automatically boot into a Live TAILS OS. If that's what you're going for then sure, that will work.

Comment: dont understand. can tails from external hdd connected via usb?